# Unable to connect to remote mongodb (using SSHTunnelForwarder) if the local host (from where i am running the code) has a mongodb as well

Tags: python, mongodb

While using the code mentioned in [How to connect remote mongodb with pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718547/how-to-connect-remote-mongodb-with-pymongo/42763361#42763361) I am able to connect to the remote mongodb where the local host machine does not have a mongodb. If the local host machine (from where the code is executed) has a mongodb, the scripts connect to the local mongodb & not the remote one.

I was expecting that the code will connect to remote mongodb but the code was connecting to local mongodb.

Comment: You need to pass remote machine IP address and not localhost.

Comment: I provided the remote machine IP address & not localhost

Comment: If it connects to localhost mongodb as mentioned in your question while connecting to remote one, it is pretty clear something is wrong with connection string.

Comment: I got the issue, in the connection string, I was using pymongo.MongoClient('127.0.39.1:27018'......) instead of pymongo.MongoClient('127.0.39.1', server.local_bind_port...)

Comment: [Default MongoDB Ports](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/). 27018 on your local machine is likely to be used by the local Mongo instance. The local tunnel entry point cannot be that port in this case.