# Connect to mongo database, given ssh key

Tags: python, mongodb, ssh, rsa, pymongo

I am trying to use pymongo to connect to a mongo database.

I have been given:
DB_name
DB_username
DB_password
DB_port
SSH_address
SSH_username
mongo RSA private key (.pem file)

I have tried running

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(host=SSH_address,
                     port=DB_port,
                     username=DB_username,
                     password=DB_password)

client.list_database_names()
```

but get a `timed out` error.

How can I pass the remaining information (such as the RSA private key) to `MongoClient`, so that I can successfully connect?

Comment: You need to use a ssh tunnel service of some sort.
heres an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42763361/10770370).

Comment: Thank you. In the end, what made it work creating a folder `~/.ssh` and adding in the `.pem` file

Answer (score 1):

Using SSH tunnel client to connect the MongoDB client works for me:

```py
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (MONGO_HOST, MONGO_PORT),
    ssh_username=MONGO_USER,
    ssh_password=MONGO_PASS,
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 27017)
)
```