# how do I use pymongo behind proxy that require authentication

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

how do I use pymongo behind proxy that require authentication?

I am able to find settings for ssh tunnel servers, such as 
[How to connect remote mongodb with pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718547)

But I am working on a environment that is behind a firewall that need to use proxy authentication. How do I config for that? For OSX terminal I use something similar to this:

```
export http_proxy="username:password@ip address:port number"
```

I find this new feature for socks5 proxy authentication https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-734, but I am just looking for basic or NTLM authentication methods, is it supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [forked](https://github.com/benjamintenny/mongo-python-driver-proxy) pymongo official repo and used python-socks to add http/socks proxy support.
Note: DNS resolving still done by pymongo not through proxy.

If you installed pymongo before you need to remove it first:

```
pip uninstall pymongo
```

Install it with git:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/benjamintenny/mongo-python-driver-proxy
```

Here is an example for your case:

```py
import os
import pymongo
# Set http proxy with credentials
os.environ["MONGO_PROXY"] = "http://username:password@127.0.0.1:8080"
# Connect to db as normal
client = pymongo.MongoClient("your-mongodb-url")
db = client.test
print(db.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

`pymongo` does not use http protocol.
You can not use `http_proxy`.

See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-1182 for details.

But you can use socks5 proxy

for example：i use `v2rayN` + `proxifier` on my windows

[image]

[image]

[image]